# IF clause in ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table like the following:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | time | message |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  |  10  |    x    |
| 2  |  12  |    y    |
| 1  |  13  |    z    |
| 2  |  14  |    x    |
| 1  |  15  |    y    |
+----+------+---------+
```

I want to write a query that returns the most updated message per id. Here is my query:

```
WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time DESC) as rn
    FROM ##TempTable
)
SELECT *
FROM tmp
WHERE rn = 1
```

which returns:

```
+----+------+---------+----+
| id | time | message | rn |
+----+------+---------+----+
| 1  |  15  |    y    | 1  |
| 2  |  14  |    x    | 1  |
+----+------+---------+----+
```

I want to add a condition that, for a specific id, if I see message "z" then just keep that row no matter what the time is, but if "z" is not among the messages keep the most updated row for that id. So, the desired output is like:

```
+----+------+---------+----+
| id | time | message | rn |
+----+------+---------+----+
| 1  |  13  |    z    | ?  |
| 2  |  14  |    x    | 1  |
+----+------+---------+----+
```

Any idea how I can modify the query?

Comment: Can you add more sample data?

Comment: tag your database

Comment: `order by case when message = z then 0 else 1 end, time desc`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wanted to keep it simple. The key is the timestamps are different and the messages can be anything. We want to keep the most updated message per id unless there is a specific message "z" for an id in any of its timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by case when message = 'z' then 1 else 0 end desc, time desc ) rn
    from data ) t 
where rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fb1e6bbccc9b744ab38d2d66aeb859a)*